# inkscape in WSL2 fails after installation Segmentation fault

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, segmentation-fault, inkscape

I am trying to install inkscape on Windows10/WSL2/Ubuntu 20.04 and am encountering the below error. I have tried "apt purge" and "apt install" to no avail.  I cannot find much online, so I suspect I am doing something wrong, but I do not know what.

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(inkscape:5803): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 08:32:13.299: _gtk_style_provider_private_get_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(inkscape:5803): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 08:32:13.299: _gtk_style_provider_private_get_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(inkscape:5803): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 08:32:13.299: _gtk_style_provider_private_get_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

Emergency save activated!
Emergency save completed. Inkscape will close now.
If you can reproduce this crash, please file a bug at https://inkscape.org/report
with a detailed description of the steps leading to the crash, so we can fix it.
** Message: 08:32:13.299: Error: Inkscape encountered an internal error and will close now.

Segmentation fault
```

Progress.  I have little experience with this type of program on wsl2 and it seems that I need a server program to view the output.
I am following these instructions to install XLaunch in Windows, but have not yet figured out how to connect inkscape to this terminal window.  When I type

```
 xhost +localhost
```

I get

```
 xhost:  unable to open display "0:0"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468421/gtk-warning-cannot-open-display-launching-background-gtk

Comment: There is a Windows version of Inkscape.  Why don't you use that instead of the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Wow. Okay, I feel dumb. I use Windows as an OS, but spend all of my day in WSL2...  Thank you for pointing out the obvious!

Comment: It's ok!  We often miss the obvious.  I do run Inkscape from time to time and my suggestion would be to try running it on Ubuntu standalone (maybe booting from USB); not as a subsystem.  That might not be the cause, but at least you'll remove a lot of factors.

Comment: `I use Windows as an OS, but spend all of my day in WSL2` -- Dual boot Ubuntu with Windows. then. The native version of Ubuntu is much better than WSL2

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I am starting with a computer that has Windows installed. Is there a way of making it a dual boot computer without having to reinstall everything?  I miss my single boot Ubuntu computer, but there are a few times that I need Windows functionality.

Comment: Of course you can dual boot Ubuntu without reinstalling Windows or removing Windows. See https://medium.com/linuxforeveryone/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-and-dual-boot-alongside-windows-10-323a85271a73 If you get stuck somewhere, you are welcome to ask a new question on this site.